# Running Perl throughC# code

Tags: c#, perl

I'm trying to run a perl script through C# code. The perl script takes a text file as input and creates two new files as output (doing some text processing in between). When I run the perl script through C# using the below code, it seems to start executing, but no files are created. Whats the problem? Syntax error?

```
        ProcessStartInfo perlStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"c:\Perl\bin\perl.exe");
        perlStartInfo.Arguments = "c:\\Perl\\DOC-MAT.pl " + "c:\\Perl\\comb1.txt" + "c:\\Perl\\comb1.mat";
        perlStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        perlStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        perlStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        perlStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;

        Process perl = new Process();
        perl.StartInfo = perlStartInfo;
        perl.Start();
        perl.WaitForExit();
        string output = perl.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Here, comb1.txt is my input file, and comb1.mat and comb1.clabel should be the files getting created by the perl code.

Comment: 1) Does the program have write permissions in `C:\Perl` ? 2) Is it possible the files are being written to standard out and thus into `string output` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as though you are missing a space between the two file arguments in your string concatenation.

```
perlStartInfo.Arguments = "c:\\Perl\\DOC-MAT.pl " + "c:\\Perl\\comb1.txt" + "c:\\Perl\\comb1.mat";
```

Should be:

```
perlStartInfo.Arguments = "c:\\Perl\\DOC-MAT.pl " + "c:\\Perl\\comb1.txt " + "c:\\Perl\\comb1.mat";
```

Perhaps a better alternative is to build up an array or List of argument strings, and use `string.Join` to do the concatenation.

```
var args = new List<string>();
args.Add(@"c:\file1");
args.Add(@"c:\file2");

psi.Arguments = string.Join(" ", args);
```

The above will work in .NET4, previous versions may require you to call `args.ToArray()` before passing it to the join method.

**Important edit:** Also, I think you need to swap the last two lines to prevent the process waiting indefinitely for the output buffer to clear. See [Process.StandardOutput (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx) for more details.