# Failed to convert xml to csv using perl script through c#

Tags: c#, windows, perl

I have the following code for converting xml to csv by using perl script. When I run the perl script through c# but there is no files are created and string output become empty.
What is the problem?
I have the perl script with .txt extention, Is this ok or not?

```
string filePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())) + "/Files/SAVVIS_CDR_1806012231.XML";

if (Path.GetExtension(filePath) != "csv")
            {
                ProcessStartInfo perlStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe");
                string perlScriptFilePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())) + "/PerlScript/formatter_savvis.pl.txt";
                string csvFilePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())) + "/PerlScript/";
                perlStartInfo.Arguments = perlScriptFilePath + " " + filePath + " " + csvFilePath;
                perlStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                perlStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                perlStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                perlStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;

                Process perl = new Process();
                perl.StartInfo = perlStartInfo;
                perl.Start();
                perl.WaitForExit();
                string output = perl.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            }
```

Could you please anyone help me to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What problem are you referring to?

Comment: Why is this tagged with [tag:perl]? I don't see any Perl code, just Windows process handling

Comment: @StefanBecker I added the `perl` tag, but to be fair, I also added the `c#` tag. OP doesn't seem to know what's going on or what their question actually is.

Comment: Much as I love perl... if you're using C#, why not do it directly in that language?

Comment: You may need to flip the order of the calls to `perl.WaitForExit();` and `perl.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();` -- see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9258187/3744182) to [Running Perl throughC# code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9258068/3744182) for details.  But beyond that we need to see a [mcve], you do a lot of manipulation of files paths and such, are you sure directories and files actually exist at the stated location(s)?  Try calling `File.Exists(string)` and `Directory.Exists(string)` in the debugger to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

First, to find out what went wrong:

```
string error = perl.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
```

Also, make sure you have necessary permissions to create files in the output directory. You may try to run your process with Admin privileges to find out if it's a permission issue:

```
perlStartInfo.Verb = "runas";
```

You may want to run your entire host process with elevated permissions for this.

*(This is only to figure out if it's a permission issue! If it's the case, grant the output directory the necessary permissions, and if possible don't automatically run scripts with admin privileges in production environment)*

There also may be errors in the perl script itself.